# PrimeFaces datePicker set current date on enter

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I use the PrimeFaces datePicker. After the calender opens I want to apply the current date when enter is pressed and no date was selected.

[image]

This works in the jQuery datePicker (https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) but not in PrimeFaces. If there is an option for this behaviour I fail to see it.

It ist working in PrimeFaces v8.0 but not in v11.0.0.

Thanks in advance for any help!

### Workaround

For v11.0.0 I can still use the calendar component. There the behaviour is still the same as in v8.0.
So I have a temporary workaround.`

### Solution

I used JavaScript code from Melloware and turned it into a function. Since I have a lot of datePickers in the application without a widgetVar I used the given event to determine the component.

```js
function applyDateOnEnter(event) {
    const datePicker = PrimeFaces.getWidgetById(event.target.parentNode.id);

    if (event.keyCode === 13 && datePicker.getDate() === null) {
        datePicker.setDate(new Date());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn this into a function if you want but here is how to do it:

```xml
<p:datePicker 
id="basic" 
value="#{calendarJava8View.date}" 
widgetVar="dpBasic" 
onkeydown="if (event.keyCode === 13 &amp;&amp; PF('dpBasic').getDate() === null) { PF('dpBasic').setDate(new Date()) }" />
```

Comment: I tunred it into a function, using the event to get the datePicker, because I would have to ad widgetVar to many calendars in the application.

Comment: Yep that is what I would do too..